# Beginner Question, help on how to consider this problem

Tags: calculus

I would like some help on how to consider this problem, if this is not the forum then a pointer to a more suitable place would be appreciated.

imagine a little guy on a flat plane, walks in a random path away from a starting point.

he has to return to the starting point within some time frame.

the plane he walks on is a little bit slippery and has a small slope.

everytime he walks, if uphill he'll walk a little bit less, if downhill he'll walk a little bit more.

i need to know when the little man has walked the furthest he can so he can turn around.

he knows how far he walks each step so can infer the slope and direction.

i'm a programmer by history so when i think of this problem i think of things like storing the different walking rates in a 360degree array and using this with the direction of the starting point and the time remaining to know when to turn around.

but this is a calculus style problem isnt it? 
and can probably be expressed in some more elegant way?

thanks

edit: he walks only integer steps in any one of 360 degrees

edit: the work of the slope is simply to give some sort of subtraction of step length or addition of step length depending on direction. you could imagine it like a wind blowing in one direction if it's easier.

edit: he walks away in any direction he likes, generally away, but when instructed he'll walk straight home.

edit: when i talk about uphill or downhill im thinking of tilting the plane, an alternative is to consider it a flat plane and a wind which causes the guy to walk further in one direction and less in another

edit: thanks for all the comments so far, and apologies for my use of the language :)

edit: i think this is a time question, at what point in time must he make his way directly back knowing he will walk at x distance/time in the required direction

bump

Comment: Are there given paths or restrictions of the walk (typically e.g. only horizontal and vertical moves are allowed by integer steps)? In which format is the 'geometry' of this walk plane is given (slipperiness and (local) slopes)?

Comment: If his path is always random (i.e. he doesn't turn round and walk back exactly the way he came) then you're guaranteed he'll return to his starting point... but it may take a very long time indeed.  If he's going to walk back exactly the way he came, then just turn round after half the time has gone.

Comment: If the plane is flat it can't have down hill and uphill. Are you concerned about time or effort? The word "can" can have several meanings (time, energy, effort,etc.).  Why would he choose hills anyway? The more you specify the problem, the easier to get somewhere with the solution. If he has finite Energy E to spend, and to go from point A to B , you need to spend energy $e_{ab}<=E$, you can then begin to formulate some equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first look at a slightly simpler problem and then at the general one. First assume there are no slopes. Then after every step the walker can compute where he is in the coordinate system and how far he is from the origin. If he can walk back to the origin and still have time for 2 steps left afterwards he can make another random step, otherwise he should return to the origin immediately.

If you introduce slope, the question arises whether the walker knows the slopes at any given point or whether he only knows the slopes at points and directions he has walked previously. Additionally, are the slopes symmetric? That is, is walking backwards exactly the opposite slope?

If he knows all slopes he can use the same algorithm as for the flat case. Otherwise he can only estimate how long it would take him back to the origin and a priori the only reliable estimate is going back the way he came.